# Serialize and Saving an ArrayList of double [] in Java

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, io, save

I want to serialize and save an arraylist that contains a double [] arraylist in java. Here is my code.

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null; 
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null; 
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null; 
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null; 

public void writeArrayListToFile(ArrayList<ArrayList<double []>> arraylist, String outputFilePath){

    System.out.println("Start saving the file at  : " + outputFilePath);

    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath , true);
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(objectOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(arraylist);
        System.out.println("Arraylist Saved Successfully...");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

But I get an error and following is the stack trace.

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at com.fyp.imur2.SaveArrayListToFile.writeArrayListToFile(SaveArrayListToFile.java:24)
    at com.fyp.imur2.JPanelJFreeChart.btnSaveGestureCollectionActionPerformed(JPanelJFreeChart.java:380)
    at com.fyp.imur2.JPanelJFreeChart.access$5(JPanelJFreeChart.java:375)
    at com.fyp.imur2.JPanelJFreeChart$6.actionPerformed(JPanelJFreeChart.java:166)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Can someone help me to solve this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to pass fileOutputStream while constructing the instance of ObjectOutputStream

```
objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

on the line

```
objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(objectOutputStream);
```

You try to call the constructor with the objectOutputStream object, which is null. Looks like you meant to call it with fileOutputStream, like this:

```
objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
```